# Flex CSS properties?

Tags: css, apache-flex, skinning

Does anyone know of a handy master reference list of all the various CSS properties available for skinning Flex?

Basically a single reference of all the style properties and their definitions and usage examples in skinning.

Stuff like

```
close-button-up-skin:   Embed("assets/buttons/close.png");
close-button-over-skin: Embed("assets/buttons/close1.png");
close-button-down-skin: Embed("assets/buttons/close2.png");
```

and not so obvious properties like

```
separator-skin:      Embed("assets/general/separator.png");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the most extensive list of Flex 3 Styles](http://www.loscavio.com/downloads/blog/flex3_css_list/flex3_css_list.htm) that I have ever seen consolidated in one place. The docs have them all, of course, but they are scattered and livedocs is sometimes less than fun to sift through.

Answer (score 2):

The styles vary based on the component you're looking to skin. The reference docs have a full list of styles for each component:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html